# Error-cannot find declaration of element 'bean' - wildfly

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, wildfly-10

I am new to development, i just stated to build a spring project using eclipse mars, java 8, spring 4.2.5, wildfly 10.0.0 and using maven.

I am getting error( **cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'**) when i deploy war file in the deployment folder.

For similar kind of question's i found answer to add beans, check whether capital **L** for xsi:schemaLocation, removing the version, i checked that too but nothing worked `

```
<beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">
```

`

I am attaching the Spring-Servlet.xml and pom.xml

> Spring-Servlet.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mac" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

> pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.macquire</groupId>
<artifactId>EAD</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>EAD Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
<jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
<spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>EAD</finalName>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance.

> Update

After adding beans i am geting compilation issues

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mac" />
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans:beans'.
>       - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/
>        beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) 
>        the root element of the document is not .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420395/cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-beans)

Comment: @aribeiro after following the link you have given i am getting compilation issues

Comment: Those issues appear on Eclipse?

Comment: yes its coming on eclipse

Comment: I'd suggest you to clean, rebuild and updated the dependencies of your Eclipse project. I've copied your *spring-servlet.xml* to my Eclipse and no XML error occurs.