# Cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I got problem on simple project. Im using Spring Tool Suite 3.8.3. Could you help me?
There is short version of errors.

> HTTP Status [500] – [Internal Server Error]
>
> Message Servlet.init() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] threw exception
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 64; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'
>
> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

DispatcherServlet-context.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
 <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" />
 <context:annotation-config />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.kk.gamestore" />
 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="messages" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

Web.xml

```html
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.kk</groupId>
  <artifactId>gamestore</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
</project>
```

security-context.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
  
 <security:http auto-config="true">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/games/add" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
  
  <security:form-login login-page="/login" 
               default-target-url="/games/add"   
               authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
 </security:http>
 
 <security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider>
   <security:user-service>
    <security:user name="Admin" password="Admin123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
   </security:user-service>
  </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same `Spring Framework` version.

You already have:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thus `4.0.3.RELEASE` and `3.1.0.RELEASE` are **not** equals. Select one of them, but be careful about which version, it because that `Spring Framework` must match for the required version for `Spring Security`.

Check the documentation for `Spring Security`, if `3.1.4.RELEASE` requires `Spring Framework` 4.0.x or 3.1.x series

Furthermore, for **all** the `Spring` **.xsd** reference, remove the version. For example

From: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"` To: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"` (Remove **-3.2**)

Without the version, Spring is able to select the higher `.xsd` version according the `dependency` defined in your `pom.xml` file. The `.xsd` files are located of course with the jars.

Comment: Big thanks for answer, i checked versions and took higher, but still i got same problem.
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml] is invalid;(...) cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Have you got any ideas? I deleted versions too. You said i have to delete versions from xsd. Should i delete it too in dispatcherservlet-context? If i thinking good if i don't have versions in code i got more compatible app.

Comment: (1) Be sure to refresh the project to reflect the new Maven settings. (2) How did you create each .xml? through the IDE?

Comment: I copy my xml from similar project and changing a little, but settings was set same and its worked in past. I refreshed it. Tomorrow i will make new rebuild this project but still got same problem at this moment. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I suggest you create each `.xml` file from the scratch through the IDE support, something about 'bean file definitions', with that some namespaces are included by default, and the IDE offers a 'visual' way, through a tab pane located in the bottom when the file is open, to add or remove namespaces (with and without versions). Thus you only should copy just the bean definitions.

Comment: Solution: I changed versions to same versions in pom.xml and i changed code in DispatcherServlet-context like in other topic - link below. If u got similar problems check your versions and servlets.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420395/cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-beans