# Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. Error while loading xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, spring-bean

Below is the xml code, I am getting this error
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

I am using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext for loading this xml and I have all the jars in manifest.mf

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
        DataSourceTransactionManager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Oracle DB DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL" />
        <property name="username" value="IDCSITCORE" />
        <property name="password" value="IDCSITCORE" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="CommonTranMan" class="panacea.boot.tranman.CommonTranMan">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

--update
This is the error which I get

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 101; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

I have this as a fat jar inside an ear deployed in jboss eap 6.4.

I have no problem when I run it as a standalone application but when deployed in jboss, I am facing this problem

Class1.java

```java
public void method1()  {
        try {

        ApplicationContext   ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");


        CommonTranMan c = ctx.getBean(CommonTranMan.class);


            returnDto = c.callUpdateValues(_dtoobject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I will call this method1 from some other java class in different project.

```java
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.method1();
```

pom.xml for building fat jar

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>panacea</groupId>
    <artifactId>springapp3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springapp</name>
    <description>New app</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                      <manifest>
                        <mainClass>panacea.boot.Class1</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420395/cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-beans)

Comment: @Sterconium, No it didnt work, I tried them

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using ? Can you also provide complete exception details /

Comment: I am using Spring 5.1.9 release and this is a spring standalone jar present inside an EAR

Comment: I have tried your code and tested in my system, I am not able to get that kind of error. Please recheck once again or you post the code with other details.

Comment: @Sambit, I have posted more details as you asked

Comment: a standalone jar created how? Make sure you are including all the metadata files and merge ones that are the same (each Spring jar has certain metadata files which when not available will break stuff).

Comment: @M.Deinum created the jar using maven build, can you tell a little more about those metadata files and all

Comment: All the spring.* files in the `META-INF` directory, those have to be merged together else one will overwrite the other. One of those includes the locations of where to find the xsd files for spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum i will add my pom.xml also now, can you check if I am missing anything in  that?

Comment: Also why are you creating a new application context? This code is potentially dangerous as you are basically restart the application each time you need a bean. You should load it once and reuse it (or even better let the container handle of all your dependencies).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199231/discussion-between-smootherbug-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Using the assembly plugin won't work afaik, as that simply overrides files. You will need something like the maven-shade plugin to have the capability to merge files instead of overwriting them. However instead of doing it yourself I would suggest using Spring Boot instead of figuring it out yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum The EAR contains one web project war and remaining all jars, This is the first time I am bringing spring into this for a functionality, so I cannot have one context for the whole application as this only jar needs spring(or please correct me if I am wrong and I am new to spring framework).

Comment: Each time you call the method the application context will be constructed, eventually  leading to all sorts of memory issues. Your war should load the file (using the `ContextLoaderListener` or load it once and reuse). However that isn't related to the issue you have which comes from the fact that you are using the assembly plugin whereas you should use something like the shade plugin and merge the resources into one file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Consider I am loading my xml file in my war project using ContextLoaderListener, Then how am I supposed to use it in the Class1.java I have?